# Cannot import name 'init' from 'colorama'

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, colorama

I'm trying to use Colorama but can't seem to get it to work. I installed it with `pip install colorama`, and version 0.4.1 was installed. Then I took an example from someone else on here:

```
import colorama
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

print (Fore.RED + "My Text is Red")
```

But I'm getting an ImportError:

```
cannot import name 'init' from 'colorama'
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: try removing the 'from colorama import init' and just doing `colorama.init()` instead

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init()
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a problem like this one but in my project I getting this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Fore' from partially initialized module 'colorama'

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. Please use the comment section under the original question for follow-ups. If you think your question is different, you can create your own question. I would recommend you create your own question, **and with additional information** regarding your code and what you try to achieve.